# SAS MAcro flow explanation

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Following this schema [image]

I can understand that macro are resolved before the PDV is even created. But i realy can't figure out how from this code.

```
data ds;
    input id  name $ value ;
    datalines;
    1 pluto 111
    2 paperino 222
    3 trump 333
    4 topo 444
    5 pippo 555
    ;
run;


%macro test(var) / mindelimiter=',';


    if &var = "pippo"n then in0_&var. = name;
    else out0_&var. = name; 


%mend test;

data want;
    set ds;
    %test(pippo);
    %test(arj);
    %test(frank);
    %test(pluto);
    %test(george);
run;
```

i get this output[image]

CAn someone explain the inner logic of this process ?

Comment: Shouldnt it be: if "&var" = "pippo"n then... because you want to compare strings here? this would at least remove the empty name-columns... The way it is now you look for variables called pippo, arj,... and compare them with the string "pippo"n

Comment: Ok, i've corrected but still i can't understand the out. The output is exactly equal to the input. And in any case thinking like a python programm  calling a method or a function i'm expecting only "out_&var." columns name, but there are a lot more columns , i realy realy can't undestand where they come from.

Comment: I am not sure what you are planing to do. At them moment, for every row in your dataset you call 5 times the macro with different names. So the output is as i would expect. What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: Yes, i deleted my answer because i am still not sure what the output you expect should look like. Maybe you can add your expected output to the question?

Comment: Sorry i think you was right. if "&var"n = ... and call just 1 time the macro with name as value. %test(name). That was the output i would like. But my questione is still open. How does SAS work ?

Comment: I added some more comments to my undeleted answer, i hope i explained the parts you where puzzling about...

Comment: You have posted this problem many times and I still don't know what you WANT to happen.  Please post an example input data and output data, in the form of SAS data step (not pictures). To me your problem statement is incomplete because you have described the CONTROL table that you want to use to define the rules that you could use to generate your output, but you haven't provided an example of the actual dataset that you want to apply the rules or the output it should generate.

Comment: the question is about why SAS is doing this. It's general question not  related to my specific problem. In kl78's answer there are some very usefull hints about the sas inner usage of macro variable, this is why i've accepted his answer, even if he doesn't realy answered my question. and my question is realy simple: why sas is doing this output.

Comment: Turn on the MPRINT, MLOGIC and SYMBOLGEN options and run the program and you will see exactly what SAS is doing for each of your macro calls.

Comment: Great that was a question i would like to ask but i didn't. You answered a never asked question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand your comments, you expect a result with 4 columns, id, name in and out, and always only in or out has a value.

But you call the macros 5 time for every row. You should call it only once for every row, then you will get the expected result.

In that case you have to remove the " at "&var" which i stated in my comments, because you are working with a variable here, not a comment (corrected my code)

Variables inside a datastep will be created even if they are in an if or else clause which will never be used. 
So you created an in and an outvariable for every name you called your macro with in the way you did before
To avoid this you could use a macro if-else, because then only the clause which is true will be visible to the datastep.  e.G.:

```
%if "&var" = "pippo"n %then in0_&var = name;
%else out0_&var = name;
```

But this will not work if var should be used as a variable, because then you would get in0_name instead of the variable-value of name because the value of the variable "name" is not known to the macrocompiler.

Also you have to be carefull how to use the macrovariable, if it should be used as string inside your datastep, you have to use "&var", otherwise it will be interpreted as a variable.

The macro resolves all &-values with there macrovalue, after this the datasteps interprets the step. 
So in this case you would not need a macro, you could just use the if-else in the datastep instead of your macrocall , eg:

```
data want;
set ds;
if name = "pippo"n then in0 = name;
else out0 = name;
run;
```

they way you want it, you should use this:

```
%macro test(var) / mindelimiter=',';
if &var = "pippo"n then in0 = name;
else out0 = name; 


%mend test;

data want;
set ds;
%test(name); /*This is called for every row in your dataset, so if you have 5 macrocalls, 
they will be called 5 times for every row in your dataset*/
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's becoming more clear. Just one more thing. I'm expecting a column for each name. something like "in_name", where name is the value of the cell of my datatset. Anyway great answer i need to study it deeper to fully appreciate macro and variable usage.

Comment: @arj:Hm, the problem for this is that the value of the variable name is not known to the macrocompiler, so you would have to call the macro with a string. If you know for which row which string should be used, you could use something like  if _n_=1 then %test(pippo); if _n_ = 2 then %test(arj)... and use the macro-if-else inside the macro, which i described in my answer

Comment: Great! I'll check this post many times in future . Thanks a lot.

Comment: There would also be some solutions to create a variable for each name, but all that i can think are a Bit complicated, maybe i will add one later

Comment: I would say that if you want to know how to do this precisely, it should be its own question - this question has its answer.  There are good ways to do what you want exactly, but you should ask that question, and provide the exact expected results.

Comment: Where is the variable named `"PIPPO"n` (which is the same thing as a variable named `PIPPO`) in the input dataset that you want to compare to the variable named `&VAR`?

Comment: @tom it is id 5 in the input dataset, you can see it in the question, i did not copy that part to the answer

Comment: ID 5?  ID is a variable in the data set. 5 is a value of the variable ID the fifth observation of the dataset. What is PIPPO?  Are you saying that you want a new variable named PIPPO with the value of 5? What is the value of PIPPO for the other four observations?

Comment: @tom: i gave the answer, not the question, so i dont want any new variable, i only  try to help the questioner. In the dataset "ds", the row with id 5 has the value pippo for the column "name", as you can see in the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a macro as you have defined it.

```
%macro test(var);
if &var = "pippo"n then in0_&var. = name;
else out0_&var. = name; 
%mend test;
```

And you call it with parameter `var` set to the value `pippo` the it will generate the code:

```
if pippo = "pippo"n then in0_pippo = name;
else out0_pippo = name;
```

Notice that this code is comparing the value of `pippo` to the value of `pippo` (since you are using a name literal). That will always be true. So it will always set `IN0_PIPPO` to the value of `NAME` and it will never assign any value to `OUT0_PIPPO`.

If you call it some other value of `var`, such as `FRANK`, then it will compare the value of that variable to `PIPPO`.

In your example data step where you are calling this macro there are no variables named `pippo` or `frank` so when you reference them SAS will create new variables with missing values. So they will always be equal.  Hence all of the INO... variable will be set to the value of `NAME` and all of the OUT0...  variables will be unassigned.

The picture you posted shows that SAS has done exactly what you asked it to do.